# UITableViewCell with large image isn't fluid

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view, and i want to do the classic list with images and text.

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath. All works fine without the image elaboration, but with this is very slow to present the viewcontroller, and the scroll isn't fluid.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    NSDictionary* element = [dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }


    NSString* imageUri = [element valueForKey:@"uri"];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageUri];
    CGFloat wImg = image.size.width * cell.frame.size.height / image.size.height;

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(wImg, cell.frame.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



    cell.textLabel.text = [ element valueForKey:@"text"];
    cell.imageView.image = newImage;

    return cell;

}
```

I have big images (iphone photos), what is the better way to do this?

Comment: Why is the image resizing necessary?

Comment: @Pol you can use `async dispatch` to do `UIGraphicsEndImageContext `, and you should put the those code to the `if cell ==nil {} `

Comment: @aircraft thank you, putting code inside if() the scroll problem is resolved. Can you write code with 'async dispatch' please?

Comment: @fabe because if you put in image with frame of 3000x(i don't remember) in a frame of 50x50 you don't see it very well

Comment: @Pol Okay, wait a moment.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than resizing every time you load the cell, you'll get better performance if you cache the resized images and use them instead.

Comment: putting inside if(cell == nil) image transformation i've resolved the problem of scrolling, now my problem is the slow load. 
With your solution i'll do the work for every image, like putting code in   if(cell == nil)

Comment: You'll always have a slow load because you need to resize the images to display the cell. If you load the images on to the cell asynchronously you'll find this fixes the slow loading time as well.

Answer (score -1):

Resizing image with core graphics is very costly operation and is affecting user experience causing the scroll to be not fluid.

Simply use image and set `contentMode` property of `cell.imageView`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";<br/>
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    NSDictionary* element = [dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }


    NSString* imageUri = [element valueForKey:@"uri"];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageUri];


    cell.textLabel.text = [ element valueForKey:@"text"];
    cell.imageView.image = newImage;
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't how it works. Although the image is shown smaller, the larger image is still backing it and that is affecting animation. If you run this through instruments, you can see this for yourself.